# How do I return the branches which have no manager? (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return the branches which have no manager.

[image: Here are the tables]

And this is what I tried:

```
SELECT branchno, city FROM branch
WHERE branchno IN
(SELECT branchno FROM STAFF
WHERE position <> 'Manager');
```

And it returns:

```
 branchno |   city
----------+----------
 B005     | London
 B007     | Aberdeen
 B003     | Glasgow
 (3 rows)
```

Comment: Your query would return all the branches that have a non-manager employee.  What else did you try once that query didn't return the right result?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using `not in`

```
select *
from branch
where branchno not in (
  select branchno from staff
  where position = 'Manager'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like below. BTW, your posted query should as well give you the desired result (per your post title). What else you are looking for?

```
SELECT b.branchno, b.city 
FROM branch b
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM STAFF WHERE branchno = b.branchno
AND position = 'Manager');
```